# How to produce a relationship matrix from a dataset?

Tags: r

I would like to use R to produce a relationship matrix from a list of known relations.
For example, with the following dataset :

```
John Green
Mary Blue
Mary Red
John Blue
```

I would like to have :

```
       Green Blue Red
John     1     1   0
Mary     0     1   1
```

I didn't found how to do this.
Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `table`.

```
people <- c("John", "Mary", "Mary", "John")
cols <- c("Green", "Blue", "Red", "Blue")
df <- data.frame(people, cols)

table(df)

      cols
people Blue Green Red
  John    1     1   0
  Mary    1     0   1
```